# problems with sign out, cookies and devise on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I have been trying to sign in after signing out on my application using devise but I am having an issue with the cookies I think because I have to refresh my web page in order to sign in again. I tried using activerecord-session_store gem and I follow the steps to configure it. I mean, I installed the gem, I generated the recommended migration on the gem documentation and generated the table using rake db:migrate command, I also changes the session_store.rb file but I feel that I am missing something to make it work since I tried it and the same happens. Please help me if you feel I am missing something or if you have other solution for this problem. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error. Can you check your server logs?

In your ApplicationController please add the following and check if you get an error.

`protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

Comment: Hi Eelco, it cant be a CSRF error because I have that line-code from the beginning "protect_from_forgery with: :exception" and no error is reported